# Carrierwave error: Argument error: Invalid base 64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, carrierwave

I'm using Carrier-wave gem to upload images to my Azure blob container. The uploads work well on my localhost and on heroku. But when I deploy to my Azure server, it gives the following error:

```
12:02:35 web.1  | Started POST "/admin/images" for 41.75.85.2 at 2015-11-30 12:02:35 +0000
12:02:35 web.1  | Processing by Admin::ImagesController#create as HTML
12:02:35 web.1  |   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"", "hint"=>"", "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8d79566b30 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20151130-10-1bcjsse.png>, @original_filename="haba_cousins.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"haba_cousins.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "alt"=>""}
12:02:35 web.1  | #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8d79566b30>
12:02:35 web.1  |    (0.5ms)  BEGIN
12:02:35 web.1  |   SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "images" ("picture", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["picture", "haba_cousins.png"], ["created_at", "2015-11-30 12:02:35.767230"], ["updated_at", "2015-11-30 12:02:35.767230"]]
12:02:35 web.1  |    (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
12:02:35 web.1  | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 397ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
12:02:35 web.1  |
12:02:35 web.1  | ArgumentError (invalid base64):
12:02:35 web.1  |   app/controllers/admin/images_controller.rb:16:in `create'
```

In my Image.rb model, I have:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :picture, ImageUploader
end
```

I have google the error but can't seem to find info I can use.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.